# siteUrl not updating

Tags: config, siteurl

Experiencing a headache on a client site where the siteUrl declared in general.php is not being reflected in the Control Panel (which is always showing the local siteUrl) and therefore also the template on the site.

An abridged/edited config file here: https://gist.github.com/cole007/68382039e9ebedceabf7

Thoughts appreciated

Answer (score 3):

When setting `siteUrl` in config.php, it *overrides* the "Site URL" setting in CP → Settings → General. It doesn't show the settings in that field.

> This is being overridden by the siteUrl config setting.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Thanks - guess it was the legacy EE muscle memory that assumed this value changed. Ta

Comment: Still getting odd response - the siteUrl have set is not being reflected in the templates

Comment: Does this settings still exist?